# PHP - Результат регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
<?php

$a = '<div style="text-align:center;"><!--image_begin:https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg|--></div>';

preg_match('/image\_begin\:(.+)\|\-\-\>/', $a, $b);

print_r($b);

Array
(
    [0] => image_begin:https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg|-->
    [1] => https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg
)
```

Как избавится от `[0] => image_begin:https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg|-->` ?

То есть чтобы в результате выводилось только URL искомого изображения как единственный элемент массива. Я в регулярных не знаток по этому обращаюсь к вам.

Comment: Можно избавиться и не будучи знатоком регулярок: `unset($b[0])`. Вообще, первый элемент соответствующий всему шаблону целиком -- это нормальное поведение `preg_match`.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин я про средствами функции preg_match , без последующего форматирования массива.

Comment: Вы можете использовать утверждения (http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php) и не использовать захватывающие подмаски: `(?<=image_begin\:).+(?=\|-->)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Как избавится от [0] => image_begin:https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg|--> ?*

Можно использовать ретроспективную и опережающую проверки - они не захватывают символы, которые участвуют в совпадениях:

```
$a = '<div style="text-align:center;"><!--image_begin:https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg|--></div>';

preg_match('~(?<=_begin:).+?(?=\|-->)~', $a, $b);

var_dump($b);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'https://dl.site.com/20/NTQ3Nw==/Fists.jpg' (length=41)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php почитайте про функцию. Сама регулярка тут не причем. Если вы хотите другой массив. Создайте его из $b[1]